# Check for disks added to the system

Tags: bash, scripting, fdisk

So I am working a script that basically check if a disk has been added to the system, and if so, then do something with it (like format it or whatever).

So, the main question is...how do I list disks (or dev) that do NOT have any partitions?

I can list them with:

```
fdisk -l | grep -o '/dev/sd[a-z][0-5]'
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda5
/dev/sdb1
```

How can I list the disks that do not have any partition? I tried something like this:

```
# fdisk -l | grep -o '/dev/sd[a-z][^0-5]'
/dev/sda:
/dev/sdb:
/dev/sdc:
```

but I still get disks like sda and sdb which do have partitions. I jsut want to take `sdc` which is the only one that has no partition and is not being used on the system. Reason I want to do this is so I can put it on a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dirty quick loop doing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# get all disks into an array
disks=($(ls  /dev/sd* | grep -v '[0-9]')) 

# loop over disks in array
for i in $(echo ${disks[@]}); do
    # check if it has a partition
    diskcheck=$(ls ${i}* | grep '[0-9]')
    # if not, print it
    if [ -z "$diskcheck" ]; then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: yes! thank you! I was looping through the array but I was not doing an echo on it, that explains it. Thank you so much!